# How to notify other objects of changes in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Suppose I have an object called `ColorHolder` where one of its properties is a `UIColor` value. Suppose I also have an `NSMutableArray` that stores some `UIColors`, let's call it `colors`. I initialize a `ColorHolder` object with a value from the array as follows:

```
[[ColorHolder alloc] initWithColor: [self.colors objectAtIndex:5]];
```

Now at some point later in the program, the user changes the value in `colors` at that same index 5. What I would like is the `ColorHolder` object I initialized above, for its color value to also change when its corresponding value in the `colors` `NSMutableArray` changes. How can I set up a pointer in this way so it happens?

Comment: Really sorry about that man, I just wanted to make the question fully reflect my main problem, but obviously it was dumb on my part. Do you think implementing the observer pattern with delegates instead of NSNotification would be more efficient?

Comment: its a matter of preference, the delegate pattern although similar is distinct from observer in its conventional use.  even though they look the same you would call the receiver the observer not a delegate usually.  But yeah its kind of the same it depends on how many observers you have of different types.  If you only have one class type observing, then its pretty simple if you want to be able to bridge many existing class types to handle a notification you need to build a bridge to an event handler and using NSNotificationCenter could simplify your life and require less code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The views which you set the font (and the FontHolder whatever that does)  are not "observing" changes to the font array and the UIFont class is immutable.

You will need to use NSNotificationCenter to add an observing class which monitors this array and sends notifications to the views (and/or FontHolder(s)) which are interested.

This is a classic observer pattern.

http://blog.csdn.net/dadalan/article/details/4240733

The above blog is not a copy and paste answer for your code, but I provide it for information on the pattern in general.

Also if your really not needing to update views you could simply tell FontHolder to refresh itself from the font array anytime the user has made a change to it. Which if there is only one observer is a cheap way to implement the observer pattern.

Comment: what if it was a UIColor instead of a UIFont, something that was mutable

Comment: UIColor is not actually mutable its mutators are only there for subclasses.  What Im trying to get at here is that when you init "FontHolder" there is no connection to the array value is was pulled from.  If you modify a mutable instance it has a pointer to yes it will see it.  If you create a new instance or modify the array, the classes you created before will still point to the instance they point to.  So yes mutability makes a difference in this case.